# How to know if a sound is playing? using system.media.soundplayer

Tags: c#, audio, media

I'm create

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(path);
```

and I have  a timer that in an interval of 5 miliseconds call a method that execute the instruction :

```
if (Condition)
        player.PlayLooping();

    else

        player.Stop();
```

if  sound is playing,  playback restarts. I want to know if the .wav is playing for non restart

Comment: Is this winform or WPF ? Can you use a different Media Control ?

Comment: @ilansch is WPF and Media Control could use another to let me play the sound cyclically

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? What is your goal ? WPF has better Controls to play media files.

Comment: @ilansch my goal is to know if the sound is running,for not execute again player.PlayLooping(); which is the condition that 
i should use, if you have a solution whith better Controls to play media files in wpf is better, will be welcome,in fact I would like to recommend which is best for my goals